# cucumber feature file not picking up Step Definition in Java class but there are no error in the console after running Junit

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

[Project Structure-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41OQo.png)   [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE2Fd.png) I am writing some cucumber tests for my java project. When running cucumber class there are no error occurred in the console but as per the step definition script i have given the script to invoke browser so as per my assumption the step definition class or the glue is not called by the cucumber class.
    Can you please check and do let me know why it is not invoked.

```
Code:
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
    features={"F:/Selinium/practise-cucumber/practise1/features/login.feature"},
    glue={"F:/Selinium/practise-cucumber/practise1/src/Stepdefinition/loginmethod.java"})
    public class Runcucumber {   
    }

Step Definition code: 
public class loginmethod  {
    public WebDriver driver ;
    @Given("^User is on Home Page$")
    public void user_is_on_home_page() throws Throwable{
        System.out.println("homepagre");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "F:/Selinium/practise-cucumber/practise1/driver/chromedriver1.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();      
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println("lUNCHED homepagre");
    }    
Browser should be invoked
```

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41OQo.png)
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcxtT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your `Runcucumber` class name to `RuncucumberTest` then try again. It happened me one time.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
    features={"F:/Selinium/practise-cucumber/practise1/features/login.feature"},
    glue={"F:/Selinium/practise-cucumber/practise1/src/Stepdefinition/loginmethod.java"})
    public class RuncucumberTest {   
    }
```